# Starting Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm a newbie in Android after Googling I found if you want to call another activity you have to use
 `Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity_Name.class);`
 `//if Any Extra`
 `//intent.putExtra("", "");`
 `intent.putExtra("EmpID", EmpID);`
 `startActivity(intent);`   `

Now this is a standard approach but if you refer to the image. I'm lopping almost 20 times in the ListView (Activity1). 
[image: Work Flow]

Now what I belive that this keeps adding again and again as my app crashes later on without any proper reason and not at any particular location.

I have **disable** the **back button** on the DataCollection Screens (Activity 2, 3,4)

Hence its a pure Waterfall approach. 
Any suggestion. Should I add  `finish();` line in the last screen

`Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity_Name.class);`
 `//if Any Extra`
 `//intent.putExtra("", "");`
 `intent.putExtra("EmpID", EmpID);`
 `startActivity(intent);`
 `finish();`   `

So that it dies and goes to the previous and that dies and goes to the previous. And later landing on the ListView.

Would that be a good approach. Or is there anything where I can just call another activity like this but the system should forget all the previous activity information.

Comment: so are you going to prevent before creating many instances of the same activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there anything where I can just call another activity like this
>   but the system should forget all the previous activity information

Have a look at Intent Flags, e.g.[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the user to go backwards, finish the current activity just after starting a new one.

after

```
startActivity(intent);
```

call

```
finish();
```

If you'd like to clear the activity stack, when going to a particiluar activity find it your manifest (like "Activity 1") and add the attribute `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`

more info here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better of using `startActivityForResult` rather `startActivity`. Then, when you call an activity you know that when it finishes it will return to the Activity which called it (it will come into `onActivityResult`). This way you can achieve:

```
Activty 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 1 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 1 etc
```

or

```
Activty 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 2 -> Activty 1 etc
```

In both cases, you don't can keep "passing through" phases of an activity invisible, they can just receive the "activity you called" trigger and pass on to the next activity.